# GenomicFeatures: Keeping track of reads and scores when mapping to transcripts

Tags: r, mapping, bioconductor

I have a bed file with genomic coordinates and their scores. I want to map those coordinates to human exons and keep track of the scores.

Here is an example (just three lines of my bed file stored in a GRanges object):

```
   library(GenomicRanges)

   reads<-GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(rep("chr1", 3)),
    ranges = IRanges(c(3044402,3044562,3044827),c(3044402,3044562,3044827)),
    strand = Rle(rep("*",3)),
    score = c(0.111111,-0.101128,-0.25)
    )
   reads

   GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
         seqnames             ranges strand |     score
            <Rle>          <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
     [1]     chr1 [3044402, 3044402]      * |  0.111111
     [2]     chr1 [3044562, 3044562]      * | -0.101128
     [3]     chr1 [3044827, 3044827]      * |     -0.25
     -------
     seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

After loading the necessary libraries...

```
   library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
   library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19)

   txdb <- TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene
   exon_by_tx<-exonsBy(txdb, by="tx", use.names=TRUE)
```

...I can map those genomic coordinates to exons like this:

```
   library(GenomicFeatures)

   mapped_exon <- mapToTranscripts(reads, exon_by_tx,ignore.strand=FALSE)
   mapped_exon

   GRanges object with 1 range and 2 metadata columns:
           seqnames    ranges strand |     xHits transcriptsHits
              <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>       <integer>
     [1] uc021oez.1  [24, 24]      + |         2             158
```

I know that the genomic coordinates of uc021oez.1 (NR_036215) are chr1:3044539-3044599. This means that `chr1 [3044562, 3044562]` maps to `uc021oez.1  [24, 24]` and its score is -0.101128.

How can I keep track of this information? In other words, how can I automatically add extra columns to `mapped_exon` with the corresponding `reads` entries?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the solution! :)

```
mcols(mapped_exon)<-cbind(mcols(mapped_exon),DataFrame(reads[mapped_exon$xHits]))

mapped_exon
GRanges object with 1 range and 4 metadata columns:
        seqnames    ranges strand |     xHits transcriptsHits                         X     score
           <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>       <integer>                 <GRanges> <numeric>
  [1] uc021oez.1  [24, 24]      + |         2             158 chr1:*:[3044562, 3044562] -0.101128
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```